# Salesforce Release Update - Enable Visualforce Expression Language Apex Method Access Modifier Enforcement

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I am not able to find any documentation related to this update. Can anyone clarify what is meant by Visualforce expression language ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Visualforce expressions look like that: `{!expression}`. They can be

- references to Apex controller variables (`{!myText}`),
- fields (`{!Account.Name}`),
- action methods (`{!save}`)
- and "getters" (`{!name}` when in the apex class you have `public String getName()` defined).

There's some more info here: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/06/secure-apex-access-modifiers-for-summer-21-security-update